# How to get the definition of a stored procedure in a Linked Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the definition of a stored procedure, from another different server. When I want to see the definition locally, I can do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM sysobjects
WHERE name = 'procedure_name'
```

When I want to see how this same stored procedure is currently, I tried to do this, since it's on a linked server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [xxx.xx.xxx.xx].DBName.dbo.sysobjects
WHERE name = 'procedure_name'
```

It runs okay, no error, but I get the definition of my local procedure, not the one on the remote server. Is there a way to do this? I couldn't seem to find any information about this case.

Comment: `sysobjects` is hardly a procedure's definition. Have you tried looking in `[xxx.xx.xxx.xx].DBName.sys.sql_modules` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```sql
EXECUTE 
(
    '
    SELECT 
        OBJECT_DEFINITION(
            OBJECT_ID(N''dbo.ProcName'', ''P''))
    '
) AT [LinkedServer]
```